# Stata vs. R survival differences; weibull scale is different, problems predicting manually

Tags: r, survival, stata, prediction, weibull-distribution

I am trying to do some survival analysis in R and as a starting point, I want to make sure I can replicate a previous analysis. I notice differences and I will demonstrate them here. I feel like there is a daft explanation the user community can provide.

Let's start by using the ovarian dataset in R. We will fit a weibull distribution with residual disease and ECOG performance status as covariates. Then we will print the output using proportional hazards specification to match Stata's HR output.

```
require(survival)
require(flexsurvreg)
require(dplyr)
attach(ovarian)
ovarian <- ovarian %>% mutate(resid.ds=resid.ds-1, ecog.ps=ecog.ps-1, futime=futime/365.25) # Make it 0,1
write.dta(ovarian %>% mutate(resid.ds=resid.ds+1, ecog.ps=ecog.ps+1), "data/ovarian.dta") # Write dta
s.weib <- flexsurvreg(Surv(futime, fustat) ~ age + resid.ds + ecog.ps, data=ovarian, dist="weibull") # Fit weibull

# Function to convert AFT to PH
flexsurvPHcoef <- function(x) return(c(exp(x$coef[-(1:2)]*(-1)*exp(x$coef["shape"])), exp(x$coef["shape"]), exp(-x$coef["scale"])))
flexsurvPHcoef(s.weib)
     age     resid.ds      ecog.ps        shape        scale 
1.150309872 2.702038142 1.060599568 1.752446996 0.002799146
```

---

Now let's compare to Stata.

```
quietly stset futime, f(fustat)
streg age i.resid_ds i.ecog_ps, d(weib)
Weibull regression -- log relative-hazard form 

No. of subjects =           26                     Number of obs   =        26
No. of failures =           12
Time at risk    =  42.67761807
                                                   LR chi2(3)      =     17.88
Log likelihood  =   -20.828884                     Prob > chi2     =    0.0005

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
          _t | Haz. Ratio   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         age |    1.15031   .0515502     3.12   0.002     1.053583    1.255916
  2.resid_ds |   2.702038    2.00098     1.34   0.180     .6329054    11.53571
   2.ecog_ps |     1.0606   .6620784     0.09   0.925     .3120252    3.605066
       _cons |   .0000336   .0000906    -3.82   0.000     1.69e-07    .0066602
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
       /ln_p |   .5610131    .238929     2.35   0.019     .0927209    1.029305
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
           p |   1.752447   .4187103                      1.097156     2.79912
         1/p |   .5706307   .1363402                      .3572551    .9114478
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

We can see the resid.ds and ecog.ps are the same. As well, the shape. But the scale is off.

**So my question is, any thoughts on why only the scale parameter is different?**

---

Let's move on to estimation. flexsurvreg has an interesting ability to predict at multiple time points. Let's assume a woman is 45, has residual disease and ECOG is 0.

```
summary(s.weib, newdata=data.frame(age=45, resid.ds=1, ecog.ps=0), t=c(1:5))
age=45, resid.ds=1, ecog.ps=0 
  time       est         lcl       ucl
1    1 0.9517266 0.807744496 0.9930684
2    2 0.8464501 0.488174229 0.9681961
3    3 0.7122949 0.193976895 0.9285058
4    4 0.5702529 0.038982054 0.8762493
5    5 0.4358519 0.002925942 0.8097636
```

Not the most precise. Anyways, how does this compare to how weibull is parameterized (PH). From Stata's manual:
$$
S = exp(-exp(x{B}){t}^p)
$$

No we have to use the log scale coefficients. But let's go ahead and try and predict this manually.

```
p.weib <- function(cons, age, resid, t, p) return(exp(-exp(cons+age*45+resid)*t^p))
coef <- flexsurvPHcoef(s.weib)
data.frame(time=1:5) %>% mutate(S=p.weib(log(coef["scale"]), log(coef["age"]), log(coef["resid.ds"]), time, coef["shape"]), S=round(S, 5))
  time       S
1    1 0.01617
2    2 0.00000
3    3 0.00000
4    4 0.00000
5    5 0.00000
```

That obviously didn't really work out. What happens if we substitute the scale from Stata (-10.30166)?

```
data.frame(time=1:5) %>% mutate(S=p.weib(-10.30166, log(coef["age"]), log(coef["resid.ds"]), time, coef["shape"]), S=round(S, 5))
  time       S
1    1 0.95173
2    2 0.84645
3    3 0.71230
4    4 0.57025
5    5 0.43585
```

It's just as flexsurvreg predicted. So now that I write this, maybe I've transformed the AFT scale incorrectly. Back to my original question, why are the scales different?

Finally, some aside questions. I couldn't reproduce my actual data problem. I can't really put up that much data here. Again, `summary.flexsurvreg` gives me predicted estimates that are not the same as the `p.weib`. But, when I substitute the scale from Stata for p.weib, I get estimates different to the original summary.flexsurvreg, albeit much closer than with the scale from my log(coef) of PH. Any thoughts?

Comment: It looks like STATA's `_cons` (the constant, i.e. the scale) is given by flexsurvreg's `exp(-scale * exp(shape))`.